# How can combine multiple rows into single based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to combine multiple rows into single based on status success/failed. Please help me how can I do this?

Example-

```
Region    Sub_Region        Status    Reason
ASPAC     CRM               success
ASPAC     Genesys           success
ASPAC     Survey            success   
ASPAC     Survey_Response   failed    list index out of range
ASPAC     Survey_Int        success
LATAM     CRM               success
LATAM     Survey            success
LATAM     Survey_Response   success
LATAM     Survey_Int        success
```

If all 3 - `Survey, Survey_Response & Survey_Int` are success then only combine them into 1 as Survey only. If any of 3 is failed then Status will be failed and in reason particular sub_reson should come. Please follow the below example-

```
Region    Sub_Region        Status    Reason
ASPAC     CRM               success
ASPAC     Genesys           success
ASPAC     Survey            failed    Survey_Response Failed - list index out of range
LATAM     CRM               success
LATAM     Survey            success
```

Comment: Whats happens if multiple `failed` per `Region` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#filter failed rows and aggregate join
m = df['Status'].eq('failed')

#joined columns only if failed
df['Reason'] = (df['Sub_Region'] + ' Failed - ' + df['Reason']).where(m , '')
#remove substring afer first _
df['Sub_Region'] = df['Sub_Region'].str.split('_').str[0]


df1 = df[m].groupby(['Region','Sub_Region','Status'])['Reason'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
#append no failed rows and remove duplicates
df2 = (pd.concat([df1, df[~m]])
         .drop_duplicates(['Region','Sub_Region'])
         .sort_values(['Region','Sub_Region'], ignore_index=True))

print (df2)
  Region Sub_Region   Status                                    Reason
0  ASPAC        CRM  success                                          
1  ASPAC    Genesys  success                                          
2  ASPAC     Survey   failed  Survey_Response Failed - list index out of range
3  LATAM        CRM  success                                          
4  LATAM     Survey  success
```

Comment: Hi jezrael.. Thank you for your response. I edited my question. Your logic is working for Survey but other region is not coming. Please check once. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Shivika - Whats happens if multiple failed per Region?

Comment: Whatever logic you have written is correct.

Comment: But It should to contain other sub_region also.

Comment: @Shivika - added to answer.

Comment: Some unwanted result I am getting

Comment: index Reason Region          Sub_Region    Run_Date                           Status
0   NaN         ASPAC                 CRM  2022-04-21                          Success
1   NaN         ASPAC             Genesys  2022-04-21                          Success
2   NaN         ASPAC              Survey  2022-04-21                          Success
3   NaN         ASPAC  Survey Interaction  2022-04-21                          Success
4   NaN         ASPAC     Survey Response  2022-04-21                          Success

Comment: @Shivika - data are different like in sample? Because sample for me working correctly.

Comment: @Shivika - there are no `_` in column `Sub_Region` ? Then change `df['Sub_Region'] = df['Sub_Region'].str.split('_').str[0]` to `df['Sub_Region'] = df['Sub_Region'].str.split().str[0]`

Comment: Region          Sub_Region   Status Reason    Run_Date
0  ASPAC             Genesys  Success         2022-04-21
1  ASPAC                 CRM  Success         2022-04-21
2  ASPAC     Survey Response  Success         2022-04-21
3  ASPAC              Survey  Success         2022-04-21
4  ASPAC  Survey Interaction  Success         2022-04-21

Comment: okay sir let me check